# How fix google tag manager trigger not tracking element visibility event for id's created during A/B testing of google optimise.?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, ab-testing, google-optimize

I have setup google tag manager triggers a page where id's are used for triggering visibility of elements events. There are 2 versions of the page. I'm performing A/B testing for the both versions. To track events in variation separately I used different ID names by editing in google optimise. On testing the google tag manager the visibility events related to variant are not being triggered.

For Example:
I have used id="tech-pro" for an element in original website and changed it to id = "tech-pro-v1" using google optimise a/b testing. The visibility event for the element with id = "tech-pro-v1" is not being triggered when it appears in A/B testing.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

For elements that are dynamically modified after the page is loaded, you should enable "Observe DOM changes" option https://nimb.ws/MiozKa